# Laravel Excel how to load a view to specific row or cell?

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel Excel, I want to load a view file and set it to specific row. Is it possible to do it with laravel excel?
bellow is the code for loading view in to the sheet:

```
Excel::create('New file', function($excel) {

    $excel->sheet('New sheet', function($sheet) {

       $sheet->loadView('folder.view');

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the package doesn't offer that I this time but maybe you could do something like this.

- Create a wrapping view that you can pass some parameters to, such as a target row number, column number and inner view to include.

  ```
  Excel::create('New file', function($excel) {

      $excel->sheet('New sheet', function($sheet) {

         $sheet->loadView('path.to.wrapping.view')->with(["targetRow"=>5,"targetCol"=>10,"targetView"=>"path.to.target.view"]);

      });

  })->download();
  ```
- Dynamically generate a table based on the parameters provided to the wrapping view. The content of the view could be something like this.

  `@if(isset($targetRow) && isset($targetCol))
      table tag
      @for ($row = 1; $row <= $targetRow + 1; $row++)
          tr tag
          @for ($col = 1; $col <= $targetCol + 1; $col++)
              td tag
                  @if($row == $targetRow && $col == $targetCol)
                      @include($targetView)
                  @endif
              close td tag
          @endfor
          close tr tag
      @endfor
      close table tag
  @endif`

Comment: But if the view has nested table, excel report can't create nested tables.